# Using cursor in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE MAP_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
    select C.OBJECT,C.CLAIM,RELID
            from EPM_ E WITH (NOLOCK) 
            join #ABCD C WITH (NOLOCK)
            on E.RELID = C.OBJECT

OPEN MAP_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MAP_CURSOR INTO @OBJECT,@CLAIM
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        BREAK
    END
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        BEGIN
          SET @PAYMENT_ID = (SELECT PAYMENT_ID FROM PAYMENT 
                                   WHERE CLAIM = @OBJECT)
        END

FETCH NEXT FROM MAP_CURSOR INTO @OBJECT,@CLAIM
CLOSE MAP_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MAP_CURSOR
```

I am trying to find if all the ids are present in the table is matching with epm table, then need to end else need to select the paymentid from payment table to process it.

Can anyone help me to solve it?

Comment: Why are you even using cursors?

Comment: to loop every row to check if it is matching with epm table, if so need to end else will proceed to process further

Comment: Still not clear why you'd want cursors to do that. In any case, your second `FETCH NEXT` statement need to be inside your loop.

Comment: i got it, but also when i keep the fetch next inside, still not getting process to to loop every row.

Comment: i am just trying t check the object present in epm table(relid). if  so end the process for the object and go to next object. if it is not matching, will go to next step .e choose paymentid from payment to process.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to get the payments where #ABCD is not matched to EPM_?

Comment: Yes, for more than a million records. IF there are no payments will end for that payment ID.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, this gets all payments where there is no epm record related to #ABCD. It'll also show where there are no payments for the data in your temp table.

```
SELECT c.*,p.*
FROM #ABCD C
left join EPM_ E on E.RELID = C.OBJECT
left join PAYMENT p on p.CLAIM=C.OBJECT
where E.RELID is null
```

Comment: no it's not null. relid is primary key of epm table

Comment: where E.RELID is null would indicate there are no related records for a payment.

Comment: Yes it is correct. RELID is not NULL, AS it is primary key in epm table